# Textfields under keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

In my app there are few forms. Sometimes keyboard hides fields so user can't see what he it typing. For that case I found way to move view or scrollview up so textfields stays above keyboard. 
Problem is that on iPhone 5 I need to move view up for last 3 textfields but for iPhone 6 - only for the last textfield.

Of corse I can define all cases of fields and device screen height values. 
But I want to find more elegant solution to detect is texfield is under the keyboard on current device and is it necessary to move view?

Comment: Get the keyboard height and see if the bottom of the screen to the bottom of the text field greater is than that distance

Comment: Consider using a UITableView where each row contains a field. When focus is moved to a UITextField, scroll to the appropriate UITableView row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). Its easy to use

drop the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m and TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h source files into your project, pop a UIScrollView into your view controller's xib, set the scroll view's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView, and put all your controls within that scroll view. You can also create it programmatically, without using a xib - just use the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView as your top-level view.

Comment: Thank you. I definitely need to try

Answer (score 0):

There is a great help guide by [Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

You need to listen to keyboard notifications like

```
// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
    }
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

Comment: Applies only when there is a scrollview, Not when there is a view

Comment: Principle is still the same. You get notification, get height of keyboard, see selected UITextField and see if its container view needs to be moved up or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect which `UITextField` is the "Active" one by using its delegate method `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.

Use `textField.frame` to calculate the offset you need to set for `scrollView.contentOffset`. 
In the `- textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method you can reset the `contentOffset = CGPointZero`